# What is the struct sockadddr_dl in ws2def.h used for?

Tags: winapi, struct

```
typedef struct sockaddr_dl {
    ADDRESS_FAMILY sdl_family;
    UCHAR sdl_data[8];
    UCHAR sdl_zero[4];
} SOCKADDR_DL, *PSOCKADDR_DL;
```

I just found this struct and google doesn't provide any information.
Does anybody know what this struct is used for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exist general [`struct sockaddr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740496(v=vs.85).aspx) for any type address - which depended on `ADDRESS_FAMILY sa_family;` can be casted to another. say for `AF_INET` - we can cast pointer from `sockaddr*` to `sockaddr_in*`. `sockaddr_dl` used when `sa_family == AF_LINK`, so used for AF_LINK protocol - for example [here](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=0jY_B3gAZc0C&pg=PA89&lpg=PA89&dq=%60AF_LINK%60%20protocol&source=bl&ots=QjQNjz7atN&sig=YeX5EoP1QV281ZYm-dBpBeTwGHI&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjug-Wx1rLQAhWBlSwKHZZ1DpgQ6AEIJjAB#v=onepage&q=%60AF_LINK%60%20protocol&f=false)

used in same api where `sockaddr` used. for example [`WSAConnect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741559(v=vs.85).aspx) - you fill `sockaddr_dl addr = { AF_LINK };...` and pass as secon argument `WSAConnect(s, (sockaddr *)&addr, );`